# Class holding vector of classes

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I am learning OOP in C++ so I tried to practice a little. I want to create a "database" (using objects) of class and its students. I created a class for a student. Each have a name and age.

```
class Ziak {

public:

    Ziak(int,string);
    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }

private:

    int age;
    string name;

};

Ziak::Ziak(int age,string name) {
    this->age=age;
    this->name=name;
}
```

And I created a class of a `Classroom` , each is represented by its name , teacher and students ( vector of objects )

```
class Trieda {

public:
    Trieda(string,string);
    void fillStudents() {
        while(1) {
            int age;
            string name;
            cout << "Name: ";
            getline(cin,name);
            cout << "Age: ";
            cin >> age;

            Ziak newStudent(age,name);
            n.push_back(newStudent);

            if(cin.eof()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    string getTeacher() {
        return ucitel;
    }

    string getNamesOfStudents() {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < n.size(); i++) {
            cout << "hey " << n[i].getName() << endl;
        }
    }

protected:
    vector<Ziak> n;
    string nazov;
    string ucitel;
};

Trieda::Trieda(string nazov,string ucitel) {
    this->nazov = nazov;
    this->ucitel = ucitel;
}
```

and I am just calling its methods in `main`:

```
int main() {
    Trieda newClass("4A","Ms Foster");

    newClass.fillStudents();
    newClass.getNamesOfStudents();

    return 0;
}
```

My problem here is the method `fillStudents()` output starts pretty nice:

```
Name: // insert name
Age : // insert age
```

but the second iteration looks worse:

```
Name:Age: // insert something
```

and the third iteration is an infinite loop printing `Name:Age:` till the end of the world.

I tried to just use `cin >> name` instead of `getline`, e.g:

```
void fillStudents() {
    while(1) {
        int age;
        string name;

        cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> name;
        /*getline(cin,name);*/

        cout << "Age: ";
        cin >> age;

        if(cin.eof()) {
            break;
        } else {
            Ziak newStudent(age,name);
            n.push_back(newStudent);
        }
        cin.clear();

    }
}
```

It works. But it works like this:

```
Name: // insert name
Age : // insert age
// it works till the last one when i press ctrl+Z as eof (currently on windows)
// it outputs Age: Hey + first name ....
Hey name 2 // and so on , then it crashes
```

What causes this? I suspect it could be something with buffer not being cleared but I tried `cin.clear()` and it happened too. How can I implement it with `getline` (I wanted full name as name input e.g John Wicked).

I am trying to figure it out but I'm just a beginner with C++ so my knowledge is limited.

**Edit**

I fixed it using `cin.get()` as advised from question posted in comments, now my function looks like this:

```
void fillStudents() {
    while(1) {
        int age;
        string name;

        cout << "Name: ";
        //cin >> name;
        getline(cin,name);

        cout << "Age: ";
        cin >> age;

        if(cin.eof()) {
            break;
        } else {
            if(cin.fail()) {
                cout<< "chyba ";
                break;
            }

            Ziak newStudent(age,name);
            n.push_back(newStudent);
        }
        cin.get();

    }
}
```

What still makes me uncomfortable is the output with `cout`. It produces this:

```
Name: John
Age: 15
Name: Lia
Age: 25
Name: Age: hey John
hey Lia
```

The `Name: Age:` still gets printed after `eof`, I tried to put `cin.eof()` test at the start of the while loop but it messed up all of the output. How can I modify the code without it showing the `cout` after `eof`?

Comment: It looks like this is you issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: Why do you think it crashes? (BTW this has nothing to do with OOP).

Comment: I am propably trying to retrieve something that isnt set up yet or something out of vector size. But cant figure out why is that happening

Comment: Nay, what makes you believe it crashes? Do you get any error messages or other unusual output?

Comment: "Program has stopped working" - segmentation fault

Comment: I tried your loop on Ubuntu with g++ and it stopped fine when I hit CTRL+C.

Comment: Strange , i tried it too on linux Ubuntu and it did not throw any seg.fault... But there is a still question about the getline, i updated question.

Comment: It might help with understanding if the class names were English.

Comment: @Kupiakos his *problem* has nothing to do with his classes, he's encountering trouble with output when sending `Ctrl+z` (`eof`) to `getline` or `cin` in his `fillStudents` method, which is English.

Comment: @JonnyHenly It's a good lesson to any new user that English should be used everywhere possible for best understanding of a question.

Comment: There are no "segmentation fault" messages on Windows. What exactly did you observe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `eof` (`Ctrl+z`(`^Z`)) after `name` has been entered and after `age` has been entered. If you enter `Ctrl+z` for `name` then the `eofbit` flag will be set on `cin` but not caught until after outputting `Age:`. The reason it doesn't pause for `age` input is because:

> The extraction also stops if the end of file is reached in [the `istream`] or if some other error occurs during the input operation. - [C++ Reference - getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)
>
> Note: The `istream` in the quote above is `cin` in your code.

Your code should resemble:

```
// above code removed for brevity
cout << "Name: ";
getline(cin,name);

if(cin.eof()) {
    break;
}

cout << "Age: ";
cin >> age;

if(cin.eof()) {
    break;
} else {
// below code removed for brevity
```

Output:

```
Tested on Windows with CodeBlocks and GCC. 

Name: ^Z[Enter]

Process returned 0 (0x0)    execution time : 1.685 s
Press any key to continue.

Name: John
Age: ^Z [Enter]

Process returned 0 (0x0)    execution time : 1.685 s
Press any key to continue.
```